# windows phone 8 scheduleactiveservice reminder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using c#, the thing is I'm trying like one user press a button with a specific time a reminder create. I used the reminder in the `ScheduledActionService`, but the thing is it works only once , I want to add an if condition or something that if the reminder appeared once, it must be removed and new one created if the user pressed one more time, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you debug the program you will see that it fails because the reminder already exists. In order to add a new reminder, you have to make the name unique.